# importing project is throwing errors

Tags: android, git, github

I am getting source code from this directory [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/)   but it throwing this error. I already got many source codes from github or git but mostly not getting any error. but this time it is not solving by different tricks. any help will be appreciated

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':generateDebugProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\src\main\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\src\debug\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\src\debug\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
D:\2BVPRO'S\launcher3\launcher3\build\extracted-include-protos\debug: warning: directory does not exist.
backup.proto:21:8: Option "javanano_use_deprecated_package" unknown.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  I tried creating the path but it was getting wiped when I tried to build.

I ended up grabbing the source from https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.android.launcher3   They also note an attempt to build failed due to protos which forced the removal of backup. The source can be downloaded directly from https://f-droid.org/repo/com.android.launcher3_1_src.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

In Launcher3/protos is a file called backup.proto. In the file:

```
package launcher_backup;

//option javanano_use_deprecated_package = true; >>> remark this line out.
option java_package = "com.android.launcher3.backup";
option java_outer_classname = "BackupProtos";
```

I was able to compile this. Apparently, this is no longer in later versions of protocol buffers. I have no idea the side effects but I was able to compile, install and use with no problems.

See https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases